# Remove item from a map based on certain criteria

Tags: java, maps

Im currently working on a college project on maps in the java language.

The map is populated with the name, nationality and a couple of other statistics about a collection of golfers. The task I have hit a roadblock with is removing any players from South Africa (there are 2).

Does anyone know what function I would be looking to use in this case? I have tried all sorts to no avail!

Thank you for any help

EDIT CODE ADDED

This is my main method

```
package assessmentmaps;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class AssessmentMaps {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
//Create a new map to store golfers and info

    Map<String, Golfer> gMap = new HashMap<String, Golfer>();

    try
    {
        //Declare new File, File Reader, and Buffered Reader
        File myFile = new File("Top 20 golfers.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(myFile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = null;

        while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            //Tokenize the String
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
            //While there are tokens to be read, assign tokens to a new 
            //golfer. Create Hashcodes for each golfer and add to map.
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                Golfer g = new Golfer(st.nextToken()
                                     ,st.nextToken()
                                     ,st.nextToken()
                                     ,st.nextToken());
                String key;
                key = Integer.toString(g.hashCode());
                gMap.put(key, g);
            }
        }

    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        //If the file cannot be found, display this message
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }


    //Task 7: Delete the players from RSA
    System.out.println("\nTask 7: Delete the players from RSA");



    for(Golfer g : values)
    {
        if(g.getCountry() == "RSA")
        {
            gMap.remove(g);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(gMap);

}
}
```

This is my Golfer class

```
package assessmentmaps;
public class Golfer 
{
private String name;
private String country;
private String points;
private String events;

public Golfer(String name, String events, String points, String country)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.events = events;
    this.points = points;
    this.country = country;
}


public String getName() 
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) 
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCountry() 
{
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) 
{
    this.country = country;
}

public String getPoints() 
{
    return points;
}

public void setPoints(String points) 
{
    this.points = points;
}

public String getEvents() 
{
    return events;
}

public void setEvents(String events) 
{
    this.events = events;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return name + " " + events +" " + " " + points + " " + country;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    if (obj instanceof Golfer)
    {
        Golfer GolfPlayer = (Golfer)obj;
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(GolfPlayer.name))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    String hashStr = this.events + Math.round(Double.parseDouble(points));
    int hash = Integer.parseInt(hashStr);
    return hash;
}
```

### }

Comment: Post the code you currently have

Comment: It's impossible to intelligently answer a question with so little details. Please share the code you already have, so we at least have a common ground for discussion.

Comment: This will depend upon how you storing the details in Map. Post your code

Answer (score 0):

**Difficult to formualte a good answer with the details provided.**

### Nevertheless, I will try my best:

Assuming you have the map of the form:
`Map<String, ArrayList<String>> golferMap= new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();`
where

> String (name) is the key and
>
> ArrayList (other statistics about golfers) is the value

You can try something like this (**note: consider this just as a reference!**):

```
//after populating the golferMap
 for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) 
{
          Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry = it.next();
          if(entry.getKey().nationality.equals("South Africa")){              
              it.remove();
          }
 }
```